# Android Firebase child node listener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know if there is some callback or something that can trigger a method when a child in `Firebase database` node is change.

[image]

For example this "Users" node, each user saved by his own `UID` and all his data.
I'm looking for a method that will be trigger when ever the `profilePic` is changed.

I have tried `addChildEventListener` and also `addValueEventListener` but none of them worked.

**Here's example**

```
refToUsers.getReference(Params.USERS).child(currentUser.getUid()).child(Params.PROFILEPIC).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Glide.with(getApplication()).load(s).apply(new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .into(cvNavUserProfile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**Another method**

```
refToUsers.getReference(Params.USERS).child(currentUser.getUid()).child(Params.PROFILEPIC).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG,"DataSnapshot: " + dataSnapshot.toString());
        String profilePic = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

None of these methods are triggered when `profilePic` is changed. There is any way to work it out? like callback or listener that will triggered every time the `profilePic` is `update/change`?

Also the method can be work only when the user is on a specific Activity? Can it be triggered even when the user is not on the method's activity?

Comment: Might be worth checking the logs for anything Firebase related. Are you actually authenticated before setting the listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the values of your `Params.USERS` and `Params.PROFILEPIC` are, but please use my solution below with the hardcoded values:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String profilePic = dataSnapshot.child("profilePic").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, profilePic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Log errors
    }
};
uidRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

When adding a value event listener, the `onDataChange()` method is triggered everytime a change on the `profilePic` property occurs.

Also don't ignore errors. As you see, I have logged them in the `onCancelled()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `query`:

```
refToUsers.getReference("users").orderByChild().equalTo(currentUser.getUid()).child("profilePic").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

  ...
  ..

// and the rest of your listener
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
  refToUsers.getReference(Params.USERS).child(currentUser.getUid()).child(Params.PROFILEPIC).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String profilePic = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG,"DataSnapshot: " + dataSnapshot.toString());
            Log.d(TAG,"profile picture: " + profilePic);
            Glide.with(getApplication()).load(profilePic).apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .into(cvNavUserProfile);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Works perfect!

Comment: Seems to be the exact solution as in my answer, right?